# Best way to export Google BiqQuery results into Google Sheets using C# API

Tags: c#, api, google-bigquery

I wanted to export the BigQuery results into Google Sheets, consider the export data to be in high volume, What is the best way to do it?

I can run BigQuery(SQL Query) and loop it through to create CSV data and can upload it using GoogleSheet API, But I feel this is not the optimize way as there will be thousands of records involved, Is there any better way out.

I am expecting GoogleSheet URL in response.

Comment: Since you didn't describe the broader goal that you want to achieve, just want to point out that [it is also possible to query BigQuery from Google Sheets directly](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis). With this capability, you may not need so many different sheets, or, you can study sheets API to see if it supports create a spreadsheet with given BigQuery connector.

Comment: @YunZhang thanks for the comment, We have a web application(Portal) that providing exporting report into GoogleSheets functionality and have BigQuery as backend, what we're looking at if user request for that export then the application should fetch data and save it as Google sheet in user Google Drive. Here one option is to connect to BigQuery using SDK and fetch all rows loop it through and create byte(csv) and upload that byte data on Google Drive(using Google api) but I feel that is not optimized for high volume of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's no way of exporting from BigQuery directly to Drive *with the API*, even though it's supported in the BigQuery console. From the [BigQuery "exporting table data" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations)

> You cannot export table data to a local file, to Google Sheets, or to Google Drive.

Likewise in the ["downloading and saving query results" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results):

> Saving query results to Google Drive is not supported by the command-line tool, the API, or the classic BigQuery web UI.

Having said that, you *can* export to Google Cloud Storage, to avoid downloading all the data. As far as I can tell there's no "import from GCS" option in the Drive or Sheets APIs, but you could write a Google Cloud Function to do that. There a [blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-cloud-function-to-automate-google-spreadsheet-csv-import-d2ffb8fbe9b4) specifically covering that, leading to a [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-function2sheet/#0).

Obviously this isn't as simple as it might be, and it's entirely *possible* that in the future there'll be a way of doing this directly, but at the moment this should help you move forward.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll explore it.